# Object-C can't found method in swift protocol

Tags: objective-c, swift

I use object-c invoke a method in protocol defind with swift, but it can't work.

```
@objc protocol DataContextFacade{

func checkfetchFeedsWithNoSession()->NormalFeedViewModel?
}
```

and:

```
@objc
class ClientContext: NSObject, DataContextFacade {
func checkfetchFeedsWithNoSession()->NormalFeedViewModel?{

    return NormalFeedViewModel()

   }
}
```

controller:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ClientContext;
@class DataContextFacade;
@interface BusinessFeedsCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController

@end
```

implementation:

```
#import "Koalac_DS-Swift.h"
@implementation BusinessFeedsCollectionViewController{

CKCollectionViewDataSource *_dataSource;

CKComponentFlexibleSizeRangeProvider *_sizeRangeProvider;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
ClientContext *facade = [self getContextFacade];

[facade fetchFeedsWithNoSession];

}
```

I hidden some details. [facade fetchFeedsWithNoSession]; I open the "Koalac_DS-Swift.h" file, and find:

```
SWIFT_PROTOCOL("_TtP9Koalac_DS17DataContextFacade_")
@protocol DataContextFacade
- (NormalFeedViewModel * __nullable)checkfetchFeedsWithNoSession;
- (void)fetchFeedsWithNoSession:(NSInteger)page perpage:(NSInteger)perpage longitude:(NSInteger)longitude latitude:(NSInteger)latitude;
- (void)fetchFeedsWithSession:(NSInteger)page perpage:(NSInteger)perpage;
- (void)fetchStoreCategory;
- (BOOL)uploadImageFile:(UIImage * __nonnull)image width:(NSInteger)width height:(NSInteger)height;
- (BOOL)isUserLogin;
@end


SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC9Koalac_DS13ClientContext")
@interface ClientContext : NSObject <DataContextFacade>
+ (ClientContext * __nonnull)shared;
- (void)fecthTest;
- (void)actionTest;
- (BOOL)isUserLogin;
- (void)userLogin:(NSString * __nonnull)userName password:(NSString * __nonnull)password deviceID:(NSString * __nonnull)deviceID;
- (NormalFeedViewModel * __nullable)checkfetchFeedsWithNoSession;
- (void)fetchFeedsWithNoSession:(NSInteger)page perpage:(NSInteger)perpage longitude:(NSInteger)longitude latitude:(NSInteger)latitude;
- (void)fetchFeedsWithSession:(NSInteger)page perpage:(NSInteger)perpage;
- (void)fetchStoreCategory;
- (BOOL)uploadImageFile:(UIImage * __nonnull)image width:(NSInteger)width height:(NSInteger)height;
- (void)isUserExist:(NSString * __nonnull)userName;
- (void)clearAllData:(void (^ __nonnull)(void))block;
- (void)deleteDataStore;
@end
```

but the code "[facade fetchFeedsWithNoSession]" doesn't compile, if  I use code "[(ClientContext *)facade fetchFeedsWithNoSession]", it pass compile, does object-c can't suppout swift protocol? somebody know why?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "can't work"? Do you mean "doesn't compile", do you mean "compiles but crashes at runtime"? There's a very, very obvious bug in your code that has nothing to do with Swift. You should turn on warnings.

Comment: it doesn't compile, I edit the bug, thanks very much